# Level of detail in real analysis proofs?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working through Stephen Abbott's wonderful *Understanding Analysis* in preparation for entering a math undergrad degree this fall. A personal note about me: Friends and family tell me I tend to be periphrastic; if there's a long-winded, inelegant way of explaining myself, I'll find it. As I work through Abbott's book, I wonder: Are all the steps I'm taking (even to solve simple problems near the beginning of the book) necessary, or is my brain just doing what it always does by finding the most round-about way to do things? So I'd like to have someone critique a simple proof to see if I'm doing something wrong, or if this really is the way things are done in real analysis.

> Exercise 2.2.5. Let $\lfloor x\rfloor$ be the greatest integer less than or equal to x. Find $lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ and supply proofs if $a_n=\lfloor \frac 1n \rfloor$.

In the preceeding chapter, Abbott has already shown that $lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n =0$, so we can take this as given. Then we note that since $n \lt (n+1)$ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$, we have $\frac 1n \gt \frac 1{n+1} \gt 0$,  $\forall n \in \mathbb N$. And since by inspection $a_n = 1$, we have

$$1\gt a_{n+1} \gt a_{n+2} \gt a_{n+3} \gt \cdots \gt0,$$
so that $a_n = 0$ for $ n \ge2$. Finally, since $|a_n-0|=0$ for $n \ge2$, we must have $|a_n - 0| \lt \epsilon$, $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$ and $n \ge2$. Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$.

Is this correct? Have I included any unnecessary steps? It just seems so pathologically nit-picky! And I feel the same way about most of the other exercises in the book. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Edited it. I'd switched up $\gt$ with $\lt$.

Comment: $\lfloor \frac{1}{n} \rfloor = 0$ for all $n\ge 2$

Comment: You're saying that it suffices simply to note that $\lfloor \frac 1n \rfloor = 0$ for $n \ge 2$ without all the intervening steps?

Comment: Just thought I'd add the following comment: I think you should keep thinking exactly the way you're thinking, especially as you start undergrad. Lots of times you will find yourself stumbling through inelegant routes, but what is important is that you have explained it to yourself and internalised it, so that when you wake up in the middle of the night you know it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for all $n\ge 2$,
$$
0 < \frac{1}{n} < 1
$$
Thus, for all $n\ge 2$,
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{1}{n} \right\rfloor = 0
$$
Thus $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$

Answer (score 1):

I think you included a lot of unnecessary stuff. All that really matters is what you say in your final two sentences: that $ a_n = 0$ for $n \geq 2$, and so on.